# Execute from AWS Step Functions different steps using the same Fargate container run

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-step-functions

I'm wondering if I can execute from AWS Step Functions different steps using the same Fargate container run.

Let's say, that I have a container that depending on the input parameters makes one thing or another. Imagine that the first step triggers the container and waits for the task token to be received but the container keeps running. Later, on another step, the same container will need to send a second task id to Step functions to complete the step.

I don't want to trigger one task for each step so I would like to know if there's a way to communicate to the container the second task id to mark the second task as complete in the same run.

Also mention that I have some other lambda executions between does steps.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you want to communicate with the same container task, run in one of the following steps of your state machine, you can use Activity Task.

The container after being spun would be polling for activity with `getActivityTask` and when it receives result it can either `sendTaskSuccess` which will make the given step pass or `sendTaskFailure` which will make the step fail.

I'd recommend you this tutorial:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-creating-activity-state-machine.html

And docs about Activities:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-activities.html